# GWT RequestBuilder POST and XSS

Tags: ajax, firefox, gwt, proxy, xss

I'm using GWT 2.1.1 and in my app there is a RequestBuilder/POST that fails (cross site scripting XSS). The main cause is the different urls for client and server:

client in dev-mode: http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#...

server jetty: http://localhost:8080/myapp/

so the browser (firefox in my case) "stops" the incoming post-request.

Is there a workaround (at least for development) to continue using gwt in dev mode?
I tried the proxy config:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3131#c46

but nothing seems to happen :(

any idea?

Thanks,
Julio

Comment: Why not using the `-noserver` mode and launching your app at http://localhost:8080/myapp/?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 ? (you could also configure your Jetty to allow cross-site requests from 127.0.0.1:8888, see http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ and http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Cross_Origin_Filter )